# increasing sequence of functions modulo fixed finite error

Tags: analysis, functions, set-theory

Here we consider only functions from $\mathbb N$ to itself.  Say $f <_n g$ if $\{ i : f(i) \geq g(i) \}$ has size at most $n$.

Is it possible to have a fixed integer $k$, a $<_k$-increasing (linearly ordered) sequence $\{ f_n : n \in \mathbb N \}$ and a function $g$ such that $g >_k f_n$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, here is a proof that there is no such thing for any $k$ (after first only showing it for $k=1$) if you want the $f_n$ to be linearly ordered by $<_k$.

Assume such $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $g$ exist for some $k$. For any $n$ fix some exception set $e_n\in[\mathbb N]^k$ that witnesses $f_n<_k g$, that is for all $m\in\mathbb N\setminus e_n$ we have $f_n(m)<g(m)$.

> **Claim 1** There is no $e\in[\mathbb N]^k$ with $e=e_n$ infinitly often.

*Proof:* If there is, we can assume wlog that $e_n=\{0,\dots, k-1\}$ for all $n$. But then $f_n(k)<g(k),\dots, f_n(2k+1)<g(2k+1)$ holds for all $n$. Thus there are $n_0<n_1$ with $f_{n_0}(k)=f_{n_1}(k),\dots, f_{n_0}(2k+1)=f_{n_1}(2k+1)$,  contradicting $f_{n_0}<_k f_{n_1}$. $\square$

> **Claim 2** There is no $1\leq i\leq k$ and $e\in[\mathbb N]^{i}$ with $e\subseteq e_n$ infintely often.

*Proof:* We proof this by induction on $i$. The base case $i=k$ is already done. Lets assume that the claim fails for $1\leq i<k$, but holds for $i+1$. We assume wlog that $\{0,\dots i-1\}\subseteq e_n$ for all $n$. Since the claim holds for $i+1$, there is some $N$ so that for all $n\geq N$ we have $f_n(k)<g(k),\dots, f_n(2k+1)<g(2k+1)$. We can now find $N\leq n_0<n_1$ with $f_{n_0}\not<_kf_{n_1}$ as above, contradiction. $\square$

By Claim 2 for $i=1$, there is some $N$ so that for all $n\geq N$ we have $f_n(0)<g(0),\dots, f_n(k+1)<g(k+1)$. But once again this allows us to find $N\leq n_0<n_1$ so that $f_{n_0}\not<_kf_{n_1}$, contradiction.

Earlier I posted an answer where I wrongly assumed you only want $f_n<_1 f_{n+1}$ for all $n$. In that case, this is indeed possible. Here is my original answer:

For the purpose of this answer I do not consider $0$ as a natural number.

> **Lemma** There is a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and a function $g$ so that $f_n<_1 f_{n+1}$ and $f_n<_0 g$ for all $n$.

*Proof:*

Let $a=(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence with the following properties:

1. for any $n\in\mathbb N$ there is $i_n\leq 2^n$ so that $a_{i_n}=n$
2. if $a_m=n$ then then $a_{m+2^n}=n$

It is not hard to construct such a sequence. Let every odd entry be $1$. Say you have specified the indices where $a_l$ equals $m$ for all $m<n$. Then let $i_n$ be the least integer $\leq 2^n$ which is not any of these indices (this $i_n$ exists inductively). Then let $a_{i_n}=n$ and produce all other such indices using rule 2, i.e $a_k=n$ iff $k=i_n\ mod\ 2^n$.

Now we are up to constructing a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and a $g$ with the requested property. 
Let $f_0$ be zero everywhere. If $f_n$ is constructed, define $f_{n+1}$ as follows: If $k\neq a_{n+1}$ then let $f_{n+1}(k)=f_n(k)+1$. Let $f_{n+1}(a_{n+1})=0$. Clearly $f_n<_1 f_{n+1}$ for all $n$. The sequence $a$ basically specifies at which places we drop back to zero. Using the porperties of $a$, we can see easily that $f_n(k)<2^k$ for any $n$ and thus the function $g(k)=2^k$ dominates every $f_n$ everywhere. $\square$

Comment: Seemed worth mentioning that using the weaker (?) relation $f \in_\ell g$, iff, $\vert \{ k \in \mathbb{N}: f(k) \not\in g(k) \}\vert \le \ell$, (for $f,g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow H(\omega)$.); it's possible to obtain functions $\{ f_k : k \in \omega \}$  and $g$, for which $\in_\ell$ linearly orders the $f$'s with $g$ $\in_\ell$-above each of them.

Comment: I think your example not assuming linear order is wrong.  I was unsure how exactly you were defining the sequence $a_n$.  See my answer.

Comment: To clear up the construction of $a$: Assign every 2nd (or odd) number value $1$. Of the remaining numbers, assign every 2nd number value $2$. Of the remaining numbers, assign ever 2nd number value $3$... and so on.

Comment: @mbsq I have now adapted my proof to work for any $k$.

Comment: @NotMike Would you care to provide such an example? To me it seems like the proof above would work in that situation, too.

Comment: @AndreasLietz, very nice, thanks!

Comment: @AndreasLietz, $\omega$ was suppose to be $\omega_1$; anyway start by fixing $X^{i,j}  \in [\mathbb{N}]^{\ell}$ (where $i < j \in \mathbb{N}$)  and letting $f_1(k) = \{k\} \in H(\omega_1)$. Next, for $j > 1$, recursively define $f_j$ by $f_j(k) = \{ f_i(k) : k \not \in X_{i, j} \text{ and } i < j \} \in H(\omega_1)$. Then, for all $i < j$, we have $f_i(k) \not\in f_j(k) \implies k \in X_{i,j} \in [\mathbb{N}]^{\ell}$; taking $g(k) = \{ f_i(k) : k \not\in X_{i, i+1} \} \in H(\omega_1)$ we have $f_i(k) \not\in g(k) \implies k\in X_{i,i+1}\in [\mathbb{N}]^{\ell}$.